# Can I turn off all notifications?

Tags: macos, notifications

In the system preferences, I've set all of them to "None" for the various applications, but I'm still seeing things like software updates and battery status there in pop-ups in the top-right corner of my screen.

Is there any way to just turn off all notifications?

Answer (score 7):

**Do Not Disturb** will mute all notifications. You can enable it by opening Notification Center by clicking on the NC icon in the menubar (or sliding in from the side of the trackpad with two fingers) and turning the switch on.

[image]

You can permanently set Do Not Disturb on by going to **System Preferences** → **Notifications** and setting the schedule to "**00:00** to **23:59**".

[image] → [image]

To remove Notification Center altogether, you can run the following Terminal commands:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
killall NotificationCenter
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui KeepAlive -bool False
```

<sup>Make sure to scroll to copy the entire line</sup>

Comment: Ah, clever!  I saw both of those pieces independently, but the DND switch told me it would turn on tomorrow, so I looked right past it.

Comment: Do not disturb is my favorite friend. I enable it on pretty much every device except one and life is so much nicer having less notifications.

Comment: I'm un-checking this answer because I just got a notification that iTunes 11.1.3 is available, even though NC says it's in DND mode.  Apparently DND doesn't apply to all updates?

Comment: grgarside: A normal notification, not on the lock screen (I never lock the screen here).

Comment: @Ken iTunes update notifications aren't notifications *per se*, but rather modal dialogs by the application, thus are nothing to do with Notification Center and can't be blocked as such.

Comment: I've read the DND time range trick in a number of places, so I tried it, but at 23:59 I got all the notifications that were held up for the previous day.